# Multidimensional array into table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array

I have a bunch of arrays:

```
let CNSNRT = ["CNS", "NRT", 3637, 2113] as [Any]
let ADKANC = ["ADK", "ANC", 1192, 2200] as [Any]
let LAXMCE = ["LAX", "MCE", 259 , 2370] as [Any]
let ANCMCG = ["ANC", "MCG", 219, 2440] as [Any]
let ATLGLH = ["ATL", "GLH", 378, 2590] as [Any]
let CNSHKG = ["CNS", "HKG", 3450, 2728] as [Any]
let AKPFAI = ["AKP", "FAI", 253, 2960] as [Any]
let ADLKUL = ["ADL", "KUL", 3524, 2984] as [Any]
```

That get combined:

```
let routesArray = [CNSNRT, ADKANC, LAXMCE, ANCMCG, ATLGLH, CNSHKG, AKPFAI, ADLKUL]
```

With `print(routesArray[0])` I get `["CNS", "NRT", 3637, 2113]` and with `print(routesArray[0][0]` I get `CNS`, so everthing appears to be referencing correctly.

However, I can't figure out how to get this into a `UITableView` correctly.  Basically, each item in `routesArray` should be a cell, and the items within the arrays will define the labels in the cells.

Current code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var routesTableView: UITableView!


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return routesArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = routesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")!

    let text = "\(routesArray[indexPath.row])"

    cell.textLabel?.text = text

    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

routesTableView.dataSource = self


}
```

Yields a table with lines that look like `["CNS", "NRT", 3637, 2113]` but I can't figure out how to break those down to apply them to specific labels on the cell.  So for example `originLabel` should display `CNS` but in the next cell, `originLabel` should display `ADK`.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include you relevant table view controller code. Show what you have so far. Clearly indicate what you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you access a given array and convert it a single string using:

```
let text = "\(routesArray[indexPath.row])"
```

Since you just want the first element of the error in the `originLabel` of the cell, you need to get that first element.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = routesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")!

    let rowData = routesArray[indexPath.row]
    if let firstStr = rowData.first as? String {
        cell.originLabel = firstStr
    }

    return cell
}
```

FYI - you should not be force-unwrapping the call to `dequeueReusableCell`. It can return `nil` and your app will crash.

Comment: Great stuff.  I had to do some tweaking, but the first label is up and running.  Still confused though about what to change in `rowData.first` to get the second and third elements in the array.

Comment: `rowData[1]` gives the second value, `rowData[2]` gives the third value, etc.

Comment: Great.  Here's the new code.  For some reason the last one still isn't updating the label though.  No errors anywhere.

if let originString = rowData.first as? String { 
routeCell.originLabel.text = "Origin:\(originString)"
}
        
if let destinationString = rowData[1] as? String {
routeCell.destinationLabel.text = "Destination: \(destinationString)"
}
        
if let priceString = rowData[2] as? String {
routeCell.priceLabel.text = "Price: $\(priceString)"
}

Comment: `rowData[2]` isn't a `String`, it's an `Int`.